# How to get the most significant bit of an unsigned 8-bit type in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to get the most significant bit of an unsigned 8-bit type in C.

This is what I'm trying to do right now:

```
uint8_t *var = ...;
...
(*var >> 6) & 1
```

Is this right? If it's not, what would be?

Comment: `highest bit` - the bits are most significant and least significant, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit). All bits have the same "height".

Comment: @JL2210: You want the MSB or most significant **set** bit

Comment: No, I want the most significant bit, whether it's a 1 or a 0. Getting the most significant set bit would be pointless.

Comment: A byte has 8 bits. The MSB is bit 7. Thus if you right shift it 7 times, it will end up at bit 0.

Comment: Is bit 0 the "signed" bit? I'm trying to figure out signed integer emulation (for my Z80 emulator) right now.

Comment: There is no "signed" bit in a `uint8_t` variable, the variable is unsigned. The "signed" bit inside a signed variable that uses [twos-complementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format is the MSB, because the negative numbers have the MSB set.

Comment: Which is why I asked.

Comment: Why did you write `6` (in `*var >>6`) in first place??

Comment: I thought shifting it 7 bits would shift past the bounds of `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the most significant bit from a memory pointed to by `uint8_t` pointer, you need to shift by 7 bits.

```
(*var >> 7) & 1
```

Answer (score 6):

The most standard/correct way of masking bits is to use a readable bit mask of the form `1u << bit`. Any C programmer spotting `1u << n` in code will know that it is a bit mask - so it is self-documenting code.

So if you want bit number 7, you would write

```
*var & (1u << 7)
```

The `u` suffix is important for rugged code, since you want to avoid accidental implicit promotions to signed types.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to simply apply a bit mask and check the resulting value:

```
*var & 0x80u // 1000 0000
```